# Postgresql cancel query on client disconnect with php

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a very expensive query which gets executed from php and it can take a while to execute. Is there a way, in php, to detect if a user disconnects prior to the query being done and cancel it?

Comment: Is this one giant query or a loop of queries? http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php shows how to check if the user d/ced but that would not work if the query itself is taking the time...

Comment: Can you reduce the size of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use **pg_send_query()**, that function sends a query to the database and returns immediatly without blocking. Then you can poll to see if the user disconnected before the query finished. See this:

```
ignore_user_abort(false); 
$db = pg_connect(DATABASE_DSN);
pg_send_query($db, "SELECT pg_sleep(10000)"); // long running query
while(pg_connection_busy($db)) {
  /* You need to output something to the browser so PHP can know when the
     browser disconnected. The 0 character will be ignored. 
  */
  echo chr(0); 

  /* Need to do both flushes to make sure the chr is sent to the browser */
  ob_flush();
  flush(); 

  usleep(100000); // 0.1s to avoid starving the CPU

  if(connection_status() !=  CONNECTION_NORMAL || connection_aborted()) {
    // Browser disconnected, cleanup an die
    pg_cancel_query($db);
    pg_query($db, "ROLLBACK"); 
    pg_close($db); 
    die(); 
  }
}

//  At this point the query finished and you can continue fetching the rows
```

This approach works but has a big problem: you really need to send something to the browser to detect the browser disconnection. If you don't, **connection_status()** and **connection_aborted()** will not work. This seems to be an old PHP bug, see here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30301

So this method doesn't work when, for example, you query Postgres in the middle of a PDF generation routine. In that case the needed **chr(0)** will break the generated binary file.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use `connection_aborted` to detect if the user has disconnected it returns 1 if the client has disconnected otherwise it returns 0. There is some documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php), however its usage is self documenting and you should have no problem using it.

Comment: how do I prevent the query from blocking?

Comment: Now I'm intrigued. This will work in the middle of a query? Wouldn't the query have to finish for php to register the condition?

Comment: Well since you cant really get true threads in PHP you would need to check before the query is executed. You should consider reducing the size of the query and then checking in between them, without knowing what you are running its hard to say anything specific.

Comment: unfortunately I can't split up the query.